# How did the Higgs perturbatively give us the mass of all other particles?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, mass, perturbation-theory, higgs

In a recent conversation with my professor, he explained to me a misconception I had, in that given how physicists says that the Higgs "gives" the mass of all other particles, I was under the impression that a particle's interaction with the Higgs field is what gives it the property of mass. However, my professor explained that the Higgs boson was simply the first term in a perturbative series where each term can be recursively defined as the one before it. So knowing the first term allows us to calculate all the other terms. The other terms were the masses of all other particles and the first term was the mass of the Higgs boson, so discovering the Higgs's mass allowed us to calculate ("gave us") the masses of all other particles.

This topic came up because I am doing research in QFT with him and in the book we're using I recently got to the part where it describes self-interactions and Yukawa interactions of fields (not yet quantized) using perturbative analysis. So, my professor used the Higgs as an example of this which I may have heard of and I had to explain my misconception to him.

My question is: Where exactly does this perturbative series come from, what was it attempting to describe, and what does it and its derivation look like mathematically? it's difficult to read the literature on this and, to be frank, I don't quite have the time. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Higgs boson is a particle from the Higgs field, which fills the space and breaks a symmetry in the Standard Model. The Higgs field has a constant value, called the Higgs vev, and it gives mass to some particles by interacting with them (with its coupling constant). The Higgs boson mass depends on the Higgs field self-interaction and quantum corrections from other fields. Quantum corrections are calculated by perturbation theory, which approximates a function by a series of terms with a small parameter. Perturbation theory has some problems and limitations, such as divergences and convergence issues.

The mass of the Higgs boson receives quantum corrections from loop diagrams involving all particles that couple to the Higgs field. These corrections can be organized into a perturbative series that depends on powers of the coupling constants and logarithms of mass ratios. The first term in this series is just the mass parameter that appears in the classical potential. The second term is proportional to the square of the coupling constant and it involves one-loop diagrams with one virtual particle running in the loop. The third term is proportional to the cube of the coupling constant and it involves two-loop diagrams with two virtual particles running in different loops or one virtual particle running in two nested loops. Higher order terms involve higher powers of coupling constants and more complicated loop diagrams.

The perturbative series for the Higgs boson mass can be written as:

$$m_H^2 = m_0^2 + \Delta m_H^2 (1) + \Delta m_H^2 (2) + \Delta m_H^2 (3) + ...$$

where $m_0^2$ is the mass parameter, $\Delta m_H^2 (n)$ is
the quantum correction at $n$-th order in perturbation theory.

The one-loop correction $\Delta m_H^2 (1)$ can be computed using dimensional regularization and minimal subtraction schemes, which are methods to deal with ultraviolet divergences by introducing an arbitrary scale $\mu$ and subtracting infinite terms proportional to powers of $1/\epsilon$, where $\epsilon$ is related to the dimensionality of space-time. The result for $\Delta m_H^2 (1)$ can be written as:

$$\Delta m_H^2 (1) = \frac{3}{16\pi^2 v^2} \left[ m_H^2 \left( \log \frac{m_H^2}{\mu^2} - \frac{3}{2} \right) + 2 m_W^2 \left( \log \frac{m_W^2}{\mu^2} - \frac{5}{6} \right) + m_Z^2 \left( \log \frac{m_Z^2}{\mu^2} - \frac{5}{6} \right) - 4 m_t^2 \left( \log \frac{m_t^2}{\mu^2} - \frac{3}{2} \right) \right]$$

where $v$ is the Higgs vev, $m_W$, $m_Z$, and $m_t$ are the masses of the W boson, the Z boson, and the top quark, respectively. The one-loop correction depends on the mass of the Higgs boson itself, which means that it is not a closed expression and it requires an iterative procedure to find a self-consistent solution. The one-loop correction also depends on the arbitrary scale $\mu$, which means that it is not a physical quantity and it has to be compensated by a corresponding dependence of the mass parameter $m_0^2$ on $\mu$. This dependence is called the renormalization group equation and it ensures that the physical mass of the Higgs boson is independent of $\mu$.

The two-loop correction $\Delta m_H^2 (2)$ can be computed using more advanced techniques and tools, such as Feynman parameterization, Passarino-Veltman reduction, and numerical integration. The result for $\Delta m_H^2 (2)$ is much more complicated and lengthy than the one-loop correction, and it involves many different contributions from various combinations of particles and couplings. The full expression for $\Delta m_H^2 (2)$ can be found in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1504.05386.pdf, which also provides a detailed derivation and explanation of the calculation. The two-loop correction is smaller than the one-loop correction, but it is still significant and it can affect the precision of the Higgs boson mass measurement.

Higher order corrections $\Delta m_H^2 (n)$ for $n > 2$ are even more difficult and tedious to compute, and they require more sophisticated methods and software. However, they are also expected to be smaller and less important than the lower order corrections, and they may be neglected for practical purposes. The perturbative series for the Higgs boson mass may also have convergence issues, which means that adding more terms may not improve the accuracy of the approximation. Therefore, there is a trade-off between the complexity and the reliability of the perturbation theory approach.